# Unpinning a BoxStream to send using Tonic gRPC stream

Tags: rust, rust-futures, rust-tonic

I am new to Rust and writing a simple application that will stream some values over gRPC, using [Tonic](https://docs.rs/tonic/0.5.2/tonic/index.html). These values are initially acquired from an external library as a [BoxStream](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/type.BoxStream.html) (`Pin<Box<Stream>>`), and tonic's API requires something that implements `Stream` (which of course Pin does not).

[Tonic's streaming example](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/routeguide-tutorial.md) uses a [ReceiverStream](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/0.1.7/tokio_stream/wrappers/struct.ReceiverStream.html) to convert a mpsc channel into a stream, and spinning off a thread to push values into it. This would require a stream lifetime of `'static` which is not an option for my actual implementation because the lifetime of my stream is associated with the class that returns it.

What is the best way to provide something that implements Stream, that I can give to Tonic, from my `Pin<Box<Stream>>`?

src/main.rs (This will not compile, since BoxStream<'static, Entry> does not implement IntoStreamingRequest)

```
use futures::prelude::stream::BoxStream;
use async_stream::stream;
use tonic::{IntoStreamingRequest};

struct Entry {
    key: String,
}

fn main() {
    // Create Request
    let stream: BoxStream<'static, Entry> = api_function();
    let request = stream.into_streaming_request();

    // Send request
    //let mut client = DataImporterClient::connect("http://[::1]:50051").await.unwrap();
    //let response = client.grpc_function(request).await?;
}

fn api_function() -> BoxStream<'static, Entry> {
    Box::pin(stream! {
        let entries = vec!(
            Entry {key: String::from("value1")},
            Entry {key: String::from("value2")}
        );

        for entry in entries {
            yield entry;
        }
    })
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "tonic-streaming-minimum-example"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
tonic = "0.5"
futures = "0.3"
tokio-stream = "0.1"
async-stream = "0.3"
```

Compilation Error provided:

```
error[E0599]: the method `into_streaming_request` exists for struct `Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src\main.rs:12:26
    |
12  |     let request = stream.into_streaming_request();
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: C:\Users\tmathews\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\core\src\pin.rs:408:1
    |
408 | pub struct Pin<P> {
    | -----------------
    | |
    | doesn't satisfy `_: IntoStreamingRequest`
    | doesn't satisfy `_: Sync`
    |
   ::: C:\Users\tmathews\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-core-0.3.17\src\stream.rs:27:1
    |
27  | pub trait Stream {
    | ----------------
    | |
    | doesn't satisfy `_: IntoStreamingRequest`
    | doesn't satisfy `_: Sized`
    | doesn't satisfy `_: Sync`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send>>: Sync`
            which is required by `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send>>: IntoStreamingRequest`
            `&Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send>>: futures::Stream`
            which is required by `&Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send>>: IntoStreamingRequest`
            `&Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send>>: std::marker::Send`
            which is required by `&Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send>>: IntoStreamingRequest`
            `&Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send>>: Sync`
            which is required by `&Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send>>: IntoStreamingRequest`
            `&mut Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>: Sync`
            which is required by `&mut Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>: IntoStreamingRequest`
            `dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send: Sized`
            which is required by `dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send: IntoStreamingRequest`
            `dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send: Sync`
            which is required by `dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send: IntoStreamingRequest`
            `&dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send: futures::Stream`
            which is required by `&dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send: IntoStreamingRequest`
            `&dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send: std::marker::Send`
            which is required by `&dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send: IntoStreamingRequest`
            `&dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send: Sync`
            which is required by `&dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send: IntoStreamingRequest`
            `&mut (dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send + 'static): futures::Stream`
            which is required by `&mut (dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send + 'static): IntoStreamingRequest`
            `&mut (dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send + 'static): Sync`
            which is required by `&mut (dyn futures::Stream<Item = Entry> + std::marker::Send + 'static): IntoStreamingRequest`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that tonic implements `IntoStreamingRequest` only for types that are both `Send` and `Sync`:

```rust
impl<T> IntoStreamingRequest for T
where
    T: Stream + Send + Sync + 'static
```

But `BoxStream` is not:

```rust
pub type BoxStream<'a, T> = Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = T> + Send + 'a>>;
```

Instead of using `BoxStream` you should copy its definition and add an additional `+ Sync` bound:

```rust
fn api_function() -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Entry> + Send + Sync + 'static>> {
    Box::pin(stream! {
        let entries = vec!(
            Entry {key: String::from("value1")},
            Entry {key: String::from("value2")}
        );

        for entry in entries {
            yield entry;
        }
    })
}
```

And because the stream returned by the `stream!()` macro is already `Send + Sync` your code will compile fine.

PS: remove the unnecessary type hint at:

```rust
    let stream: BoxStream<'static, Entry> = api_function();
// should become:
    let stream = api_function(); // after the above change it's not BoxStream anymore!
```